# Call functions of 2nd class from 1st class's outside object in php

Tags: php, oop, dependency-injection

I need your guidance, may be its a very basic question but i couldn't figure out this even after lots of google search. I could access variables of other classes through Eureka class but not their functions.

This is my case:

Class autoload function in index.php

```
<?php
function __autoload($class_name)
{
    //$class_name = strtolower($class_name);
    $path = "{$class_name}.php";
    if (file_exists($path)) {
        include ($path);
    } else {
        die("{$path} file could not be found!<br />");
    }
}
?>
```

Base class, I want to access all other classes using this class's object on the html page:

```
<?php
    class Eureka
    {
        public $some_var1;

        public function get_all_settings()
        {
            echo 'get_all_settings was called from Eureka class.';
        }
    }
?>
```

Timezone class in timezone.php

```
<?php
class TimeZone
    {
        public $some_var2;

        public function get_time_zone()
        {
            echo 'get_time_zone was called from TimeZone class.';
        }
    }
 ?>
```

Location class in location.php

```
<?php
    class Location
    {
        public $some_var3;

        public function set_location($location_name)
        {
            echo 'set_location was called from Location class.';
        }
    }
?>
```

html page index.php

```
<?php
 $eureka = new Eureka;

    //**How can I achieve this ????**
    $eureka->TimeZone->get_time_zone();
    //**OR**
    $eureka->Location->set_location('some_location_name');       
?>
```

e.g. when $eureka object calls 'TimeZone' class, it should be loaded and 'get_time_zone()' method called without any errors.

Comment: Modify the constructor of the Eureka class to create new TimeZone and Location instances and store them as a properties.... `public function __construct() { $this->TimeZone = new TimeZone(); $this->Location = new Location(); }`

Comment: Thats not how it works and its not dependency injection. You could implement [__get](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php) to do it but thats just plain wrong.

Comment: Alternatively you could use the magic `__get()` method

Comment: But a "God Class" like you're describing your "Eureka" class is incredibly bad coding practise

Comment: @MarkBaker I wouldn't necessarily say that, CI is a "god" class then.  It depends if its functionally correct for the application or laziness.  And let me tell you I am a lazy coder. But I build things to build things for me, that's how lazy I am.

Comment: CI? Continuous Integration?

Answer (score -1):

You'd have to do something like this, basically you to store the other classes in the first class and then access them.  Can't pull them out of thin air after all.

```
<?php
    class Eureka
    {
        protected $someVar1; //shouldn't really use public, instead use getters and setters

        protected $TimeZone;

        //should use dependacy injection
        public function __construct(TimeZone $TimeZone = null){
               if($TimeZone) $this->setTimeZone($timezone);
        }

        public function getTimeZone(){
            return $this->TimeZone;
        }

        public function setTimeZone(TimeZone $TimeZone){
            $this->TimeZone =  $TimeZone;
        }

        public function getAllSettings()
        {
            echo 'get_all_settings was called from Eureka class.';
        }
    }

    class TimeZone
    {
        protected $someVar2;

        public function getTimeZone()
        {
            echo 'get_time_zone was called from TimeZone class.';
        }

        public function hello(){
            echo "Hello";
        }
    }


    $Eureka = new Eureka( new TimeZone() );

    $Eureka->getTimeZone()->hello();
```

As far as your code style `get_time_zone` you can technically name them how you want. I personally try to follow the `PSR-2` standard.

You shouldn't use public properties because a class should be a black box, it shouldn't expose it's implementation to the outside world. This will make it easier to refactor the class later and maintain it.

If you open it up to the rest of the code, you'll be searching in you're whole application looking where you used those properties.  You could try to argue the same of `methods` but I would say consider this.

```
class Foo
{
    protected $bar;

    public function getBar()
    {
        return $this->bar;
    }
}

$Foo = new Foo;
echo $Foo->getBar();
```

Then if you refactor it

```
class Foo
{
    protected $baz; //renamed

    public function getBar()
    {
        return $this->baz;
    }
}

//no code change requred
$Foo = new Foo;
echo $Foo->getBar();
```

Where as if you do this

```
class Foo
{
    public $bar;
}

$Foo = new Foo;
echo $Foo->bar;
```

And then change it

```
class Foo
{
    public $baz; //changed
}

$Foo = new Foo;
echo $Foo->baz; //also required changing
```

This is a very simple tiny example, but these things can quickly get out of hand.  And you really limit yourself by using `public` most novice coders look at `protected` as being more limited.  When it's the other way around.

http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/